# What is the most efficient way to farm ducats?

Tags: warframe

I am looking for a way to get a lot of ducats since I need to get the Primed mod and Prisma Gorgon that just came out a few hours ago.

I only have 200 ducats and that is the result of a lot of selling of prime parts. Where and how can I maximize the number of ducats I can get?

Comment: Partial answer.  I'd say look up the void drop tables and do the missions that reward more blueprints out of the possible drops than others.  Blueprints are worth 50 ducats, parts appear to only be worth 20.

Comment: If you have platinum, you'll often find that adverting on the trade channel as "WTB Prime anything for #p each" will yield you some results.  I generally find that 10p for 5 prime items (50 to 150 or so usually worth of ducats) is a fair trade.YMMV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer will vary greatly by your skill level.  Currently, I find that Tier 1 sabotage are actually the most efficient for me with a small group (who are skilled at finding caches).  Sabotage missions get you more than once chance for a drop.  If one tenno does the sabotage while the others find all the caches, they can be done very quickly and provide multiple drops.  Captures are also very fast, but only provide one drop and don't necessarily provide as high an average ducat price as Tier 1 and Tier 2 sabotage.  Tier 3 Defense and Survival missions with large skilled groups are also great as they tend to provide a steady stream of items with a fairly good return.

Answer (score 3):

My friends and I run T3 and T4 Captures when we need ducats. There is a fairly good chance of getting the Akbronco Prime Link, which is worth 50 ducats at the trader. If you don't have any T3 Captures, you can get them fairly often from doing T1 Defense. If you don't have those, then my favorite place to farm T3 Captures is on Cambria, Earth. This also happens to be a great place to farm for other T3 keys, but your best bet is to do nothing but void missions so you're always getting parts.

PS: Prisma Gorgon, like the others, is not worth using other than for mastery. It may even be cheaper for you to pick it up on the trading channel.

Comment: I find it's rarely worth buying Trader items on the trading channel.  Most items require only about 2 to 3 hours worth of efficient ducat farming to get.  People tend to be stingy with them (since they are not readily available) and most often are charging exorbitant prices for them.  I often get comments like "Well then wait for the trader to have it again."